# Laravel save relationship with custom foregin key

Tags: php, laravel

In my web application I have to table as `schedule_instagram_accounts` and `actions_logs`.

each row of `actions_logs` belong to `schedule_instagram_accounts` table with `schedule_id` foreign key,

`schedule_instagram_accounts`:

```
Schema::create('schedule_instagram_accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('account_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('account_id')->references('id')->on('instagram_accounts')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->mediumText('todo');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

`actions_logs`:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('actions_logs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('schedule_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('schedule_id')->references('id')->on('instagram_actions_histories')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->tinyInteger('action_type')->index();
        $table->text('log');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

`actions_logs` model:

```
class ActionsLog extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function page(){
        return $this->belongsTo(ScheduleInstagramAccounts::class,'schedule_id');
    }
}
```

`schedule_instagram_accounts` model:

```
class ScheduleInstagramAccounts extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $casts = [
        'todo' => 'array'
    ];

    public function page()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(InstagramAccount::class);
    }

    public function log()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ActionsLog::class, 'schedule_id');
    }
}
```

now I want to save data into `actions_logs` with relation ship that linked to `schedule_instagram_accounts` table

```
ScheduleInstagramAccounts::find(1)->log()->create([
    'schedule_id' => 1, // is one row of schedule_instagram_accounts table
    'action_type' => 1,
    'log' => 'test'
]);
```

I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: 
a foreign key constraint fails 
(`instacheeta`.`actions_logs`, CONSTRAINT `actions_logs_schedule_id_foreign` 
FOREIGN KEY (`schedule_id`) 
REFERENCES `instagram_actions_histories` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) 

(SQL: insert into `actions_logs` (`schedule_id`, `action_type`, `log`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, 1, eeeeeeeee, 2018-07-11 09:12:55, 2018-07-11 09:12:55))
```

**UPDATE:**

but this code work fine:

```
ActionsLog::create([
    'schedule_id' => '1',
    'action_type' => 1,  //like
    'log' => 'qqqqqqq'
]);
```

Comment: instagram_actions_histories has 1 id?

Comment: @J.Doe yes, i have that in table, http://rupload.ir/upload/55z1rnqbngzq0vlocb74.png **updated**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did a mistake in the foreign key constraint definition :

This line :

```
$table->foreign('schedule_id')->references('id')->on('instagram_actions_histories')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Should be :

```
$table->foreign('schedule_id')->references('id')->on('schedule_instagram_accounts')->onDelete('cascade');
```

One other thing Laravel is smart enough to fill the foreign key for you so you have to do just like this :

```
ScheduleInstagramAccounts::find(1)->log()->create([
    'action_type' => 1,
    'log' => 'test'
]);
```

Comment: thant was very big mistake :(

Answer (score 0):

You can add relation to schedule_instagram_accounts, but in your table actions_logs foreign key on instagram_actions_histories table. I think problem in this. Try this:

```
InstagramActionsHistories::find(1)->log()->create([
   'schedule_id' => 1,
   'action_type' => 1,
   'log' => 'test'
])
```

Or this:

```
ActionsLog::create([
   'schedule_id' => 1,
   'action_type' => 1,
   'log' => 'test'
]);
```